# jQuery - remove select option based on text not value

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have a dropdown box as follows:

```
<select id="select_Boiler">
  <option value="boiler_1645">Vaillant 831</option>
  <option value="boiler_2373">Worcester 24</option>
  <option value="boiler_3009">Vaillant 835</option>
  <option value="boiler_4354">Bosch 671</option>
</select>
```

I need to be able remove specific options using jQuery but based on the text not the option value. I've tried this without success:

```
jQuery("#select_Boiler option[text='Vaillant 835']").remove();
```

I know I can do the same with value as below and it works but i need to do it by text

```
jQuery("#select_Boiler option[value='boiler_3009']").remove();
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

you can use [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to filter based on text content of an element, but note that it will return partial matches. So `:contains('Vaillant 835')` will return `:contains('Vaillant 835')` and `:contains('Vaillant 8356')`

```
jQuery("#select_Boiler option:contains('Vaillant 835')").remove();
```

If you want to filter for equal you need to do a manual filter like

```
jQuery("#select_Boiler option").filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) ==  'Vaillant 835'
}).remove();
```

Comment: It is not working for IE11, can you please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the case insensitive option of Arun P Johny's answer.

```
jQuery("#select_Boiler option").filter(function() {
    cur_text = $(this).text().trim().toLowerCase();
    return cur_text.indexOf('Vaillant 835') != -1;
}).remove();
```